# Request access to teamsite puts user in the wrong permission group

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, permissions, access

When a user request access to our team site and I approve his/her request then the user is added to the team site members and should be added to the team site visitors instead. Is this a common behavior, or is this set as default somewhere in SharePoint?

Greetings,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes,** if you have clicked directly on the **Approve** button it will be added to the `Members` group by default.

[image]

**To Specify which group (Like visitors group) you need to do the following:**

- At the pending Requests Click on eclipse **...**
- Specify the Group Name

[image]